# Self referencing algorithms for multiplication of binary polynomials

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms

Currently, I am going through the paper "[Space-efficient quantum multiplication of polynomials for binary finite fields with sub-quadratic Toffoli gate count](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.02849v2)" by Iggy van Hoof.

Two algorithms are given to multiply two binary polynomials: $MULT1x_k$ and $KMULT$.

[[image: <span class=]$MULT1x_k$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ckqw.png)

[[image: <span class=]$KMULT$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkOtP.png)

As can be seen, both the algorithms are self-referencing. In particular, $MULT1x_k$ calls $KMULT$ in line 4, while $KMULT$ calls $MULT1x_k$ in line 2 and 3. How can this be implemented in practice? I am trying to implement these algorithms in Qiskit.